# Get the second last items from string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a string like this,

> > abcd acdd aaaaa sdfd sddff mmdd xyxy

I want to get **mmdd** from this string.

I tried it like this,

```
string para = "abcd acdd aaaaa sdfd sddff mmdd xyxy";
string getChars = para.slice(-2)[0]; // it shows xy  i need to get mmdd
```

Comment: C# strings don't have a `slice` method so I assume this is nothing to do with C#....?

Comment: And JavaScript doesn't have type names so I assume this is nothing to do with JavaScript...?

Comment: It seems he has mixed the 2 languages. Let's just call that pseudocode.

Comment: How can we have 5 answers to a question where we don't even know what language is being used? Seriously people, please don't waste everyone's time like this...

Comment: this is Jquery..

Comment: @HimBromBeere Please don't hammer a question when it's completely unclear, notice OP is asking about jQuery....

Comment: And no one is bothered to handle when there are less than 2 words

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using JavaScript for this, the following will do the work:

```
"abcd acdd aaaaa sdfd sddff mmdd xyxy".split(" ").slice(-2)[0];
```

Comment: what if there are less than 2 words?

Comment: @Saksham - Less than two means, 0 or 1 item. In these cases, it will return blank, and the only (which is first and last both) item respectively. Also, if there are exactly two items, it will return the first item because seeing backwards, its the second last item.

Comment: I know the behavior. I wanted to point that incase of a single word, that should be returned not black.

Comment: @Saksham -- It returns blank for **zero** words i.e. a blank string. For single word, it returns the word itself.

Answer (score 0):

Using reverse.

```js
var String ="abcd acdd aaaaa sdfd sddff mmdd xyxy";
console.log(String .split(' ').reverse()[1]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: what if there are less than 2 words?

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to select words and then take out the 2nd last word

```js
var para = "abcd acdd aaaaa sdfd sddff mmdd xyxy";
var words = para.match(/[a-z]+\w/g);

var getChars = words.slice(-2)[0];

console.log(getChars);
```

Comment: what if there are less than 2 words?

Answer (score -1):

you can split use split, then string array length - 2 to get 2nd item to the last:

for C# (since you have added C# as your tag a while ago):

```
string para = "abcd acdd aaaaa sdfd sddff mmdd xyxy";
string[] paraArr = para.Split(' ');
string result = paraArr.Length > 1 ? paraArr[paraArr.Length - 2] : string.Empty;
```

but for javascript, same methods:

```js
var para = "abcd acdd aaaaa sdfd sddff mmdd xyxy";
var paraArr = para.split(' ');
console.log(paraArr.length);
var resultText, arrLength = paraArr.length;
if (arrLength > 1) {
  resultText = paraArr[arrLength - 2];
}
console.log(resultText);
```

Comment: why the downvote?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but this will crash at runtime. Consider what `para.Length` is, and compare that with the number of elements in the array returned by `para.Split()`

Comment: yeah.. thanks for pointing that out.. that was tricky.. updated my answer

Comment: OP is asking about JavaScript, not C#

Comment: @DavidG, see my edit.. a while ago, he included C# in his tags. and as you can observe, he declares variables just like in C#, whereas it would error if he uses javascript.

Comment: what if there are less than 2 words?

Comment: @Saksham, good point.. edited my answer.